# Check if Groovy script is being executed directly

Tags: groovy

In Python, one can check [if a script is being invoked directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) by checking if `__name__ == '__init__'`.

Is there any equivalent to this in Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easy way is to compare the current class name (using `class.simpleName`) to the actual executing file script name
here is an example:

let's create the first class in `M.groovy` file:

```
class M {
    static main(args){
        def m = new M()
    }
    def M(){
        def thisClass = this.getClass().simpleName
        def callingClass = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).name.with{ it.take(it.lastIndexOf('.')) }
        println("thisClass: ${thisClass}, callingClass: ${callingClass}")
        if (thisClass == callingClass){
            println 'Calling from M class...'
        } else {
            println 'Calling from outside.'
        }
    }
}
```

Now from external class e.g. `T.groovy` you can call an instantiate `M` class: `new M()`.
when you execute `M.groovy` you got:

```
thisClass: M, callingClass: M
Calling from M class...
```

and when you run `groovy T.groovy` you'll get:

```
thisClass: M, callingClass: T
Calling from outside.
```

Hope this helps.